# Symfony form and iterator input checkbox / text

Tags: forms, symfony

I have this form:

```
->add('task', 'text')
->add('dueDate', 'date')
->add('save', 'submit')
```

I would like to iterate an input text / checkbox using data from database.

[update] in other words I want to print fields according to data inside my database.
Like a foreach but all using the form symfony ($result as $val){ print'input type="checkbox" value="valore"' }

Can you help me ?

Comment: Please clarify your problem and **ask** a real question.

Comment: Do you think of embedded collection of forms? URL: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is likely the form bulder: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#building-the-form

```
//In your controller
$results = //get data from the database here

$form = $this->createFormBuilder();

foreach($results as $result){
    $form->add($result['field_name'],$result['field_type'],array('data=>$result['field_value']'));

    //Where field_name would be something like task, dueDate, save, etc.
    // field_type would be something like, text, choice, hidden
    //then to set the data for the field you pass it in the data option aka field_value
}

$form->getForm()->createView;
```